# how to move file from inbound remote directory to another remote directory using transactionSynchronizationFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, ftps

I have a requirement is to read file from a FTP remote directory insert payload values into database and then move file from remote directory /in to remote directory /archive of same FTP server.

I am using spring integration @InboundChannelAdapter and able to invoke ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor setAfterCommitExpression. I am struggling to find a way to construct a spel parse expression to move from inbound remote directory to another.

Answer (score 0):

The `setAfterCommitExpression` is executed against `Message` as a root object.
That message is exactly what `FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` is producing.  The payload of this message is an `FTPFile`. There are also some additional headers:

```
            messageBuilder.setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_HOST_PORT, uri.getHost() + ':' + uri.getPort())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY, uri.getPath())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE, uri.getFragment());
```

So, you may call some service from that expression like `@myFtpMoveService.moveRemoteFile(#root)` and accept in that method a `Message` with all the info you needed to determine the remote file, its name and directory.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Messaging Gateway

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface FtpGateway {
  @Gateway(requestChannel = "ftpChannel")
  void sendFile(File file);
}
```

and @ServiceActivator

```
 @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
  public MessageHandler ftpFileTransferMessageHandler() {
    // MessageHandler config..
  }
```

and provided @Gateway method `"@ftpGateway.sendFileToArchive(payload)")` as SPEL to the setAfterCommitExpression in TransactionSynchronizationFactory

```
  spelParser.parseExpression("@ftpGateway.sendFileToArchive(payload)"));
```